# How to apply filter across two templates

Tags: xslt, xpath

In another thread another developer helped me by providing the awesome answer below.

Basically two templates are used to retrieve all of the data I need to present in my table.

My question now is how do I now apply a filter that will filter to both templates? I can successfully use `xsl:value-of select="@Name[contains(.,NameIWant1)]"` in the `xsl:template match="SubGroup"` but I cant figure out how to get it applied to `xsl:template match="Data"`. I tried to use various name ways to no avail.

Thanks in advance you guys have been a huge help in me learnig XSLT!! kg

Sample XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Sample.xsl"?>
<DataView Client="Client1" ID="1000" TimeStamp="12/7/2011 5:35:09 PM">
<Group ID="5000" Name="GroupName1">
<SubGroup ID="7000" Order="0" Name="NameIWant1">
<Data ID="1" Name="DataName1" Order="0">1</Data>
<Data ID="2" Name="DataName2" Order="0">2</Data>
<Data ID="3" Name="DataName3" Order="0">3</Data>
<Data ID="12" Name="DataName4" Order="0">4</Data>
</SubGroup>
<SubGroup ID="8000" Order="0" Name="NameIWant2">
<Data ID="1" Name="DataName1" Order="0">6</Data>
<Data ID="2" Name="DataName2" Order="0">7</Data>
<Data ID="3" Name="DataName3" Order="0">8</Data>
<Data ID="12" Name="DataName4" Order="0">9</Data>
</SubGroup>
</Group>
</DataView>
```

`Sample.xslt`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My Data</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Subgroup</th>
                        <th>DataName1</th>
                        <th>DataName2</th>
                        <th>DataName3</th>
                        <th>DataName4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SubGroup">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this ...

```
____________________________
NameIWant1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
           | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

I would like to get..

```
____________________________
NameIWant1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter which `SubGroup`'s to display based on the `Name` attribute?

Comment: Yes the name attrubute in Subgroup

Comment: I think I understand. Take a look at my answer. If it's not what you're trying to do, let me know and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to filter `SubGroup`'s by name is to move the expression into the match pattern, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="SubGroup[contains(@Name, 'NameIWant1')]">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

And then ignore all other `SubGroup` elements with an empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="SubGroup"/>
```

Complete stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My Data</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Subgroup</th>
                        <th>DataName1</th>
                        <th>DataName2</th>
                        <th>DataName3</th>
                        <th>DataName4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SubGroup[contains(@Name, 'NameIWant1')]">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SubGroup"/>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you again lwburk for your expertise. I've placed an order for my beginning XSLT book LOL